# C# doesn't pick up dropdownlist items on jquery bind

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, drop-down-menu

I get a JSON object and fill my drop down list with the data where **d.data.reqs** is the data I want to bind, the drop down list is **#ctl00_mainContent_ddlReqs** (this works):

```
        $.each(data.d.reqs, function (key, value) {
            $("#ctl00_mainContent_ddlReqs").append($('<option>' + value.title + '</option>').val(value.id).html(value.title));
        });
```

So now I have a drop down list with some items in but when I'm on server side and try to get the data, it shows an empty list.

```
ddlReqs.SelectedValue(); // shows nothing
```

and even when checking if there any items in the element, it shows no items in the drop down list.

Why is this happening?

Comment: I guess you are posting them, and that you are using ASP.Net?

Comment: @smoksnes yes i am

Answer (score 0):

Bodzilla, Could you provide some C# code. If the json is inserting the data into the DDL correctly, it could be a problem with your .Net code.

Comment: Rahh safe, you sorted my life out